# How to run Parse Cloud Code by a specific user?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

How can call [Parse.Cloud.run](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.1.0/Parse.Cloud.html#.run) by specific user in javascript api?

Server code

```
Parse.Cloud.define('createChatRoom', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user == null) {
        res.error({
            message: 'No request user',
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can input user's sessionToken to third parameter object is not expressed in [official doc](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Cloud.html#.run).

```
Parse.Cloud.run(
    'createChatRoom', 
    { title: roomTitle }, 
    { sessionToken: user.getSessionToken() } // User specific user's session
);
```